# Why can't I adjust partition size precisely with parted (KDE Partition Manager)?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, kde4

**Context:**  I want to clone my Kubuntu 12.04 (the Pustulated Priapulid) installation from one logical volume to another, prior to doing a dist-upgrade to 14.04 (the Teratogenic Tardigrade) on the original.  These two logical volumes were created the same size, or so I thought, using one of the [`parted`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Parted) frontends (probably a GParted live cd) a few years ago, but now I have discovered that there is a difference of about a megabyte in their sizes, which prevents [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) from writing an image taken from the larger one onto the smaller one.  (Cloning from the smaller onto the larger one worked fine, a couple of years ago, when I still had no idea they weren't exactly the same.  The procedure is described [here](http://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/102_restore_image_to_different_partition.faq#102_restore_image_to_different_partition.faq).)

Specifically, sda5 and sda7 were created as ~15.62 GiB logical partitions, in the same extended partition on a WD 298.1 GiB rotary hard drive, but their exact sizes are respectively 16,775,118,848 bytes and 16,774,070,272 bytes; sda7 is 1,048,576 bytes (exactly 1 [MiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)) smaller than sda5.  [KDE Partition Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Partition_Manager) (1.0.3) has the ability to change the size of a partition in increments of 1 MiB, but when I queue the operation of moving the start of the next logical partition forward ("to the right") by 1 MiB to make room, it describes this under Pending Operations as 
"Move partition '/dev/sda8' to the right by 0.99 MiB and shrink it from 9.76 GiB to 9.76 GiB" and offers no additional mebibyte of space to expand /dev/sda7 into.  Indeed, it won't allow me any latitude to expand sda7 until I have it shrink sda8 by *8 MiB* (which becomes "Move partition '/dev/sda8' to the right by 8.83 MiB and shrink it from 9.76 GiB to 9.75 GiB"); then when I tell it to add 1 MiB on the end of sda7 it queues the operation "Move partition '/dev/sda7' to the right by 4.58 MiB and grow it from 15.62 GiB to 15.63 GiB".

**Question:**  Why is `parted` behaving this way?  Is its seeming perversity actually the result of its respecting some underlying structure which it nevertheless ought to be telling me about?  Or is it just evil?  And if it is in fact possible and okay to do what I'm trying to do---viz., make sda7 *exactly* the same size as sda5---, how can I do it?  (At worst, would executing the pending operations reliably have this effect?)